# My Manjaro KDE Display Manager failed to start

Tags: arch-linux, boot, kde, manjaro, konsole

[image]

When I boot into my Manjaro KDE, it says that the Display Manager failed to start. I then login from console and try startx. But it seems like something were missing. I can't even download it since I don't know how to connect to the Wi-Fi through the konsole. I tried iwctl but it didn't recognize the command...What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this problem before when installing a new desktop environment; it happened when I forget to enable my new one. Try `sudo systemctl -f enable gdm.service` if you have gnome installed also or do the same thing except can gdm.service with your previous Display Manager (ex. `sudo systemctl -f enable sddm.service`) I hope this helps!

Source for command(s) mentioned in this answer: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-gnome-desktop-on-manjaro-18-linux